# issues with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of buttons on the left side of my page. When those buttons are clicked it shows a div. I am having an issue with one of the buttons. The one called 'Announcements'. It may be an issue for all of them, but this is the first div that I tried to put an content into. I am trying to add a table to it. What it is doing is including the next button's content into the Announcements and vise versa for the button that proceeds it. I created a JSfiddle to show what I am doing. The results are the same on my page. It shows this

```
<div id='dues'>League Dues</div>
```

in the Announcements div. It also shows my `<th>`, but if you click out of announcements and try to go back into it the `<th>`'s go away.

Why is this happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/s3muwfcg/

Full code:

```
<div class="dashboard_selection">
        <div id="dashboard_welcome">Welcome to the Admin Dashboard</div>
        <div id='user_requests'>User Requests</div>
        <div id='message_center'>Message Center</div>
        <div id='edit_rankings'>
            <div class="admin_panel_results_title">Team Rankings</div>
<?php
try {
    //Prepare
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM team_rankings WHERE user_id=user_id")) {

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ranking_id, $ranking_user_id, $ranking_firstname, $ranking_username, $ranking_division, $ranking_wins, $ranking_losses); 

        //var_dump($stmt);

        if (!$stmt) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
        }

        $stmt->store_result();
        echo "<span class='top_bottom_margin'>Select a user to modify their team rank</span>". "<br>";
        echo "<select id = 'member'>";
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<option value='{$ranking_username}' data-username='{$ranking_username}'>{$ranking_username}</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";


    } else {
        echo "<p>There are not any team players yet.</p>";
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
                <label>Wins
                    <input type="text" id="wins">
                </label>
                <label>Loss
                    <input type="text" id="losses">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div id='draft_order'>Draft Order</div>
            <div id='draft_input'>Draft Input</div>
            <div id='announcements'>
                Announcements
<?php
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

try {
    //Prepare
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    if ($announcements_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM announcements")) {

        $announcements_stmt->execute();
        $announcements_stmt->bind_result($announcements_id, $announcements_user_id, $announcements_messages, $announcements_date); 

        if (!$announcements_stmt) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
        }
        $announcements_stmt->store_result();
         $announcements_result = array();

?>
            Current Announcements
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>   
<?php
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_username; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_messages; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_date; ?></td>
                </tr>   
            </table>
<?php
        }  
    }
}
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }   
?>          
            </div>
            <div id='dues'>League Dues</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have not closed your `<div id='announcements'>`. There is no corresponding `</div>`!

Comment: I have the div closed in my file, but the results are the same. For some reason in the jsfiddle it works if I close that, but doesn't in my file. Would the full code help?

Comment: @Becky, you managed to mix up your markup, here's a fiddle with a correction: https://jsfiddle.net/s3muwfcg/2/

Comment: What do you mean I mixed up my markup? Where? I added my full code to show I have a closing div.

Comment: @Becky it's a silly mistake dude

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara What is? I have a closing div. I have looked this over 50 times and cannot see what it is.

Comment: @Becky it's like you missed closing div or it's sequence here it works for me just check it out  **https://jsfiddle.net/s3muwfcg/3/**

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara Yea, I've added that in the fiddle, but if you look at my code, you can see how I have a closing bracket. I added my code to the question.

Comment: @Becky it seems the sequencing issue between php syntax and html tags  let me look

Comment: @Becky i think you need check whether try{} catch{} is making issue or what coz  as i have seen your code you might need to give different conditions when you are using **multiple catch{}** else you need to write **try{}catch{}** block again may b i am wrong i am not saying i am right but you should try this way

Comment: So how can I change the try catch blocks? I really need them for both of those, is there a way to differentiate them?

Answer (score 0):

Your div is not properly closed

> see this [CLICK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/s3muwfcg/1/)

close a div before

```
// here 
</div> // <-----
<div id='dues'>League Dues</div>
```

Comment: I have the div closed in my file, but the results are the same. For some reason in the jsfiddle it works if I close that, but doesn't in my file. Would the full code help?

Comment: yes absolutely and i recommend to check each div which you open and close as proper dom element opening and closing are very important

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
<div id='announcements'>
        Current Announcements
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td>Message</td>
                    <td>Date</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_username; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_messages; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_date; ?></td>
                </tr>    
            </table>
    <div id='dues'>League Dues</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s3muwfcg/)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked you jsfiddle code and found that you have used `insertAfter`. I have replaced this with `html`

Additionally, you have not closed `div` element for announcements, which result in issue.

Check below code.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                     $('.panel_out input').on('click', function(){
                        var id_to_show = '#' + this.id.replace('_button', '');
                        $(id_to_show).show().siblings().hide();
                    }).first().trigger('click');
$("input.arrowBtn").click(function(){
                    $(this).siblings('.arrow-left').remove();
                    $("<div class='arrow-left'></div>").html($(this));
                });
                });
```

HTML code :

```
    <div class="panel_out">
        <div class="panel">
            <input type='button' class="panel_buttons arrowBtn" id='user_requests_button' value='User Requests'>
            <input type='button' class="panel_buttons arrowBtn" id='message_center_button' value='Message Center'>
            <input type='button' class="panel_buttons arrowBtn" id='edit_rankings_button' value='Team Rankings'>
            <input type='button' class="panel_buttons arrowBtn" id='draft_order_button' value='Draft Order'>
            <input type='button' class="panel_buttons arrowBtn" id='draft_input_button' value='Draft Input'>
            <input type='button' class="panel_buttons arrowBtn" id='announcements_button' value='Announcements'>
            <input type='button' class="panel_buttons arrowBtn" id='dues_button' value='League Dues'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard_selection">
        <div id="dashboard_welcome">Welcome to the Admin Dashboard</div>
        <div id='user_requests'>User Requests</div>
        <div id='message_center'>Message Center</div>
        <div id='edit_rankings'>gfg</div>
        <div id='draft_order'>Draft Order</div>
        <div id='draft_input'>Draft Input</div>
        <div id='announcements'>
            Current Announcements
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $announcements_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $announcements_username; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $announcements_messages; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $announcements_date; ?></td>
                    </tr>    
                </table>
</div>
        <div id='dues'>League Dues</div>
    </div>
```